Dynamic csv import using batch
I need to import daily csv files with the name "DailySummary%todaysdate%" into my postgres table. I tried using a dynamic copy function which I can't seem to figure out.
Would it be better to import csv using batch commands instead of running a .sql file?
How would I go about doing this?
I am on windows using psql. Thanks.

psql in combination with \copy or COPY will be lighting fast. Without any information about your problem, hard to help.
